# Another what am I?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

The structure is a hint as well, the punctuation is irrelevant in that sense.

tap
a
cabalistical
sum;
counterdemonstrations,
fabrications,
I
antienthusiastically
circumstantiate
unexceptionability

What am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are a:

> **CALCULATOR**

While the text may be a disguised description of your functionality, the real clue here is that:

> the number of letters in each word are 3-1-12-3-21-12-1-20-15-18, which when converted to letters via A1Z26 spells out **CALCULATOR**!

To attempt to decode the apparent mysticism of the text...

*tap a cabalistical sum*

> '[*Cabalistical*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/cabalistic)' implies 'secretive or mysterious'. These words describe the act of pressing buttons to find the answer to an unknown ('mysterious') sum.

*counterdemonstrations, fabrications, I antienthusiastically circumstantiate unexceptionability*

> These words suggest that a calculator simply (with nothing extraneous merely for show, i.e. '*antienthusiastically*') always generates the correct answers without exception. The use of '*counterdemonstrations*' and '*fabrications*' may be obfuscated ways of referring to 'subtraction' and 'multiplication', respectively - since, after all, a calculator performs calculations other than merely addition...

<sub>PS The OP explained their true intentions of the meaning of the phrase in comments below:</sub>

> <sub>It really boils down to, "You can't fool a calculator." You can type whatever twisted stream of digits and symbols you can think up - *cabalistical sums, counterdemonstrations, fabrications* - but still it will perform its pre-programmed operations systematically, unemotionally, and without deviating from its rules (i.e. it will *antienthusiastically circumstantiate unexceptionability*).</sub>

Comment: Not exactly what I was going for with the meaning of the words, but obviously, yes that's the right word. I'll have to leave off the structure is a clue initially next time, or at least convolute the translation beyond simple A1Z26. Nicely done.

Comment: Re: meaning of words; the intent was no matter what tricks you attempt, fictitious math you come up with, etc the calculator always and simply does it's job of providing a known answer to the provided input. But it's not exactly easy to come up with 12-21 letter words that fit fluidly, so the meanings had to stretch a bit. i.e. I would've rather not used counterdemonstrations, but again, 21 letters is hard to deal with. I might even like your interpretation more than my intended - just noting

Comment: @TCooper Ah, I see. I'll mention your intentions in the answer - it was hard to work out the precise meaning from words so unusual!

Comment: I can see why, sometimes I pick something around me, pick some random rules, and then force a puzzle out of it - some turn out better than others.